# Does Task.Run() code execute asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have defined this block code. Can anyone tell me if this code is **asynchronous** or **parallel**?
This block code just only an example.  It creates four threads and in the end waits for all the threads to be complete.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetSum();
        });

        var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetSum();
        });

        var t3 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetSum();
        });

        var t4 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetSum();
        });

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3, t4);
    }

    private int GetSum()
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: please add the tag of the language you are using, it will attract more people

Comment: All four task run in parallel and Task.WhenAll doesn't Stop Running of code, it just create a task that you can wait on it, if you want to wait until all task finish.
Take a look at [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I editted

Comment: 4 Task.Run can run in Parallel if the system has multiple cpu  core it can be in Parallel

Comment: But Task.Run perform action asynchronously https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It is asynchronous and parallel.

Comment: I just confuse between using Task for Asynchronous and Parallel. Does anyone explain to me? Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Nobody help to explain for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a Task doesn't directly create a thread. A Task handles threads via the ThreadPool mechanism. It is Asynchronous. This is because the static method Task.Run() returns a work queued to execute in the ThreadPool to it's caller.

Comment: So you mean 4 Task.Run execute asynchronous instead of Parallel?

Comment: I mean this block code when these 4 Task run is executing parallel not just Task.Run method

Comment: Yes, Task.Run executes asynchronously. An asynchronous method returns control back to it's caller almost immediately after it is executed - You clearly don't know the difference between this and parallel. An asynchronous method can never block a thread (or UI). The call to Task.WaitAll doesn't even block the thread, but rather it waits for the four separate tasks to complete running on their separate threads (on the ThreadPool)

Comment: yup, what if I add async and await keywork to method that contains 4 Tasks, it is still asynchronous right and don't block UI thread since this code is in window form. So what is different between added async/await keywork to this code block or not. As far as I know this code block is executing multitasking Task Parallel?